# Concatenating JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a `HashMap` in the controller:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>();
```

In the JSP page I want to access this through something like this:

```html
<c:forEach var="list" items="${requestScope.list}">
   <c:set var="testing" value="{requestScope.map}"></c:set>
   <c:forEach var="anotherTesting" items="${testing['${list.item}']}">
      <option><c:out value="${anotherTesting}"/></option>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Where `list.item` is a String but it is used for another process but I want it to be used to access the `HashMap`.

Is there a way to concatenate JSTL? Either `map.key` or `map['key']` will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess simply this would work:

```html
<c:forEach var="anotherTesting" items="${testing[list.item]}">
   <option><c:out value="${anotherTesting}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
```

Notice the difference with and without quotes:

- `${testing[list.item]}` is equivalent to `testing.get(list.getItem());`
- `${testing['list.item']}` is equivalent to `testing.get("list.item");`.

Some Note:

- You don't need to specify the scope to access the attributes, unless there is a conflict with the same name in different scopes. So, `"${requestScope.list}"` can be changed to `${list}`, and `"${requestScope.map}"` can be changed to `${map}`.
- Please use a different name for `var` attribute of outer loop. May be `listItem` instead of `list`.
- No need to set the `map` to a different variable. That `<c:set...>` is not needed. You can directly access the property of `map` attribute.

So, your loop can be modified to:

```html
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${list}">
   <c:forEach var="anotherTesting" items="${map[listItem.item]}">
      <option><c:out value="${anotherTesting}"/></option>
   </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in `${...}` is not JSTL but [Expression Language](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). You don't need to c̶o̶n̶c̶a̶t̶e̶n̶a̶t̶e̶  nest EL `${}` expressions, just add it cleanly.

Knowing this, the expression `${testing['${list.item}']}` will be `${testing[list.item]}`.

**BUT** note that this is not what you really want/need unless `testing` is indeed a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`, otherwise you will get unexpected results. From your code above, assuming `requestScope.list` is a `List<Map<String, ArrayList<String>>>`, then the code would be:

```html
<c:forEach var="listItem" items="${list}">
    <c:forEach var="innerString" items="${map[listItem.item]}">
        <option><c:out value="${innerString}"/></option>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that `${list}` is the same as `${requestScope.list}` assuming there's no `list` attribute nor in page, session or application scope, similar for `${map}`.